# Creating a custom grid from an array of arrays with angular and css

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I am wanting to create a grid of the following array:

```
[
  [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
  [ 'd', 'e', 'f' ],
  [ 'g', 'h', 'i' ]
]
```

such that I have a grid displaying them like:

```
| a | b | c |
| d | e | f |
| g | h | i |
```

But I can't seem to get things to work.

Here is a [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/grid-test-new) with what I have so far

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of data">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of row">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use table like this

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
    <td *ngFor="let item of row">
          <div class="item" >{{item}}</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using index
1. First loop by data and use let i = index
2. In second loop also use data instead of row and use item[i]

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of data; let i = index">
        <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of data">{{item[i]}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Working code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/grid-test-new-znetmq?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

With current code you are rendering rows as children of "grid" element. The result is

```
|row1|row2|row3|
|row1|row2|row3|
|row1|row2|row3|
```

that is why a,b and c are rendered in first column. css grid is especially good at implementing 2d layouts, i.e. no rows are actually needed. to implement the desired result you could for example add

```
.row {
  display: contents;
}
```

it will make css logic to apply ".item" elements as they were direct child of ".container".
Another Angular option is to render rows inside of ng-content element like this:

```
<ng-content *ngFor="let row of data">
....
```

ng-content element is a helper angular element and is not rendered in resulting markup. Or you could simply use flex or float like grids

Comment: I had tried `flex` beforehand, which does work reasonably well, but I just couldn't get the character boxes to be the same widths for some reason.
Could you possibly create an example?

Comment: just apply `display: flex` to container and `flex: 1 1 100px;` for children. they should have the same width in such case. third value could be anything. just the same for all children to apply the same proportion

Comment: I still seem to get the vertical alignment rather than rows

Comment: what behivor is required when resolution is changed? it is possible that grid would really be the best solution

Comment: Desired behaviour in question

Comment: if you want to have always exactly 3 collums than adding to original solution any of `display: contents` of `ng-content` should work